# "And" vs "with" in description lists

Tags: style, creative-writing

When should I use the former or the later? Examples:

> It was a bird. It had a black head and wings **and** a golden underbelly.
>
> It was a bird. It had a black head and wings **with** a golden underbelly.
>
> ---
>
> I went inside the building. It had small, windowless rooms **and** shelves of all sizes and shapes.
>
> I went inside the building. It had small, windowless rooms **with** shelves of all sizes and shapes.

Comment: Sorry, but single-word requests, phrasing, and re-phrasing questions are [off-topic](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/671/is-this-question-asking-for-a-single-word-on-topic/675#675) here. If you can edit this into a more substantial question, we'd consider reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wings and a golden underbelly" is better because otherwise it seems like the wings have a golden underbelly.

The second example depends on if you want the rooms or the building to have the shelves. *With* if you want to the rooms to have the shelves, *and* otherwise.

In a list of attributes, such as yours, use *and* to demark the last attribute of the main object and *with* to create a sublist of attributes of one of the main list attributes.

> The tree had green leaves with spikes and pronounced veins.

Leaves are an attribute of the tree, spikes and veins are attributes of the leaves.

> The figure had six legs, four arms and three heads with horns

The legs, arms and head are attributes of the figure, the horns are an attribute of the heads.

It is possible to use *with* with the main object:

> The tree was tall, with green leaves.

So the tree has leaves, not the attribute *tall*. C.f. "The tree was tall and had green leaves."

Answer (score 2):

The first answer by Matt Ellen is good, but excessively rigid imho.
It is just a direct consequence of the grammatical fact that `and` is
a conjunction while `with` is a preposition. So this implies indeed
that whatever follows `with` is related to what precedes it. However,
being related to does not necessarily mean being part of, as in : `he saw his aunt with his mother` (using one of the various meanings of
`with`).

While the use of `with` is quite appropriate to describe an attribute
of an attribute, and can often suggest that, it can be used
for other purposes, especially when there is no semantic ambiguity.

In addition, the conjuction `and` is somewhat bland, and creates no
relation between conjuncts. It just enumerates. Using `with` when it
can be appropriate may reinforce the conjunctive aspect by insisting
that the conjunction may have more meaning than just coincidence.

For example, in the sentence: `She wore a blue hat with a green coat.`, using `and` instead of `with` would be a sort of objective,
factual description as in a police report, while the use of `with`
puts the green hat and the blue coat in stronger relation, hence tries
to suggest something, possibly that the character has no color taste.

In the case of the bird example above, it could be that the story was
about finding an animal having a golden underbelly. Then the use of
`with` emphasizes an attribute that has an important role, as opposed
to other attributes, though it is emphasized softly which gives a
smoother style than writing `... but a golden underbelly`.

Of course, there are cases when the intention is to provide a structureless
enumeration. Then `and` should be used.

Comment: I disagree. The meaning you describe can be achieved by a comma or dash: `a black head, black wings – and a golden underbelly`. See how I repeated "black" to avoid repeating "and", but in fact two "and"s are not a stylistic problem here, rather they add a nice rythm (now with comma for a somewhat shorter pause): `a black head and black wings, and a golden underbelly`. "with" does *not* emphasize the "golden" to me, but rather feels grammatically wrong. I would avoid it (here).

Comment: My point was mainly to emphasize that there are many forms, with more or less subtle differences in meaning and structures, which may also be influenced by the overall style. Another point is that language is protean, that it varies from person to person, so that getting your meaning across is also dependent on interaction between various part, on stylistic variations, and not just on the grammatical variation of a single sentence. I did not aim at excluding, and that was just my reading, one possible reading of what some variations may mean.

Comment: I agree with all of what you wrote, except that "with" is a good choice in Alexandro's second sentence (and I mean: never and under no circumstances). But then, as you rightly pointed out, your language might differ from mine.

Comment: @what I do understand your grammatical point. But, the expression `together with` can be used grammatically instead of `and`. The question could be whether it is appropriate to abbreviate it as simply `with`, which is somewhat lighter. It may be that one way language perceptions differ is on how sentences may be abbreviated. I actually wonder how much this is codified. I will ask.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the unneccessary enumeration of body parts:

> It was a bird. It was black with a golden underbelly.

I would avoid the enumaration, because you are missing body parts that the reader is left wondering about: what about the bird's back, tail, peak, and legs? Are they black, too, or of a third color? If you say that the bird was "black with a golden underbelly, it is clear that everything is black, *except* the underbelly.

Personally, I would even drop the "It was" from the second sentence:

> **It was a bird. Black with a golden underbelly.**

If you need to *emphasize* the (unexpectedly or sought for) golden underbelly (as @babou descibed), just add punctuation or vary the sentence structure:

> It was a bird. It was black, with a golden underbelly.
>   It was a bird. It was black – with a golden underbelly.
>   **It was a bird. Black. And with a golden underbelly.**
>   etc.

Your choice will depend on the rhythm (which should match the surrounding text) and the strength of emphasis you want to achive. I put my preferences in bold face.

Comment: Hey, you're right for some reason in the picture: https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7087/7002468621_6072bb7c4b_z.jpg I only thought about its head and wings as black. Thanks.

Comment: That's a beautiful bird.